# Solving a simultaneous system of linear congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I wish to solve the following system of congruences using the Chinese remainder theorem:
$$13X \equiv 3 (\text{mod} 15), \\ 2X \equiv 6 (\text{mod} 10).$$
I have reduced this system to
$$X \equiv 6 (\text{mod} 15), \\ X \equiv  3(\text{mod} 5),$$
by multiplying the first by the multiplicative inverse of $13$ and dividing the second through by $2$. However, the moduli are still not relatively prime, so I am unsure how to solve this system.

Comment: $\pmod 5$ the first one gives us $x\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ but the second gives us $2x\equiv 1 \pmod 5$, so not compatible.

Comment: @lulu How does the first give $x \equiv_{5} 1$?

Comment: @V.Elizabeth  What do you mean? $13\equiv 3\pmod 5$ and $3x\equiv 3\pmod 5$ is the same as $x\equiv 1 \pmod 5$.

Comment: They're *inconsistent* mod the moduli gcd $5\!:\ \color{#c00}{x\equiv 1}\,$ vs. $\,\color{#0a0}{x\equiv 3}\, $ (i.e. $\,\color{#c00}{x\equiv3/13}\not\equiv \color{#0a0}{6/2\equiv x}),\,$ so they are unsolvable.  See General Easy CRT in the linked dupe for CRT for noncoprime moduli.